# Force users to type or paste correct form of string. Problem with inverting reg ex

Tags: regex, validation, input, replace

I would like to force users to type or paste correct form of string like:
a001
a025
F190
F500
GND
UNL
SFC

I've made a pattern to detect this type:

```
/(gdn|unl|sfc)|(a|f)[0-9]{1,3}/ig
```

However it need to be opposite/ inverted regular expression to replace everything not matched by my script:

```
checkAltitudePattern(e,i,control) {
    let val: string = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    let pattern = /(gdn|unl|sfc)|(a|f)[0-9]{1,3}/ig;
    let patternVal = val.replace(pattern, "");
    //console.log("patternVal",patternVal)
    if (control === 'lowerAltitude') {
        this.AltFromControl(i).patchValue(patternVal);
    } else if (control === 'upperAltitude') {
        this.AltToControl(i).patchValue(patternVal);
    }
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help.
Regards

Comment: whats the input? And do you mean by your required text above: Letter + 3 numbers, or GND?

Comment: If you add `i` flag to your pattern, you can get rid of capital letters in it, although it will allow mixed letter case.

Comment: @SteveTomlin the input is simple Angular's matInput. 
acceptable values ​​are:
string of characters
"GND"
"SFC"
"UNL"
or
3 digits prefixed with A or F

Comment: @AlexanderMashin could you help me out to place this flag?

Comment: Just replace `/(gdn|GND|unl|UNL|sfc|SFC)|(a|A|f|F)[0-9]{1,3}/g` with `/(gdn|GND|unl|UNL|sfc|SFC)|(a|A|f|F)[0-9]{1,3}/ig`.